# jQuery datepicker won't close in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, datepicker

The jQuery datepickers I've added to a page work as expected in IE 9 and Firefox 18, but do not close after picking a date in Google Chrome 24.

Here is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#fromCheck" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "-1w",
            maxDate: "+0",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#toCheck" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate || "-1w" );
            }
        });
        $( "#toCheck" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+0",
            maxDate: "+0",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#fromCheck" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate || "+0" );
            }
        });
        $( "#fromCard" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "-1w",
            maxDate: "+0",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#toCard" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate || "-1w" );
            }
        });
        $( "#toCard" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+0",
            maxDate: "+0",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#fromCard" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate || "+0" );
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is a link to a demo page:

http://www.tempuspayment.com/paymentmate/tests/apm/

Comment: On line 144 you have `onfocus="value='"`. What's that supposed to do?

Comment: Made the change. Thanks. But datepicker still does not close in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Your throwing a javascript error on line 136 that is halting the execution of your Javascript.

The offending line is:

```
<input name="FROMDATE" type="text" id="fromCheck" value="01/04/2013" onfocus="value='" size="10" maxlength="50" />
```

which should be:

```
<input name="FROMDATE" type="text" id="fromCheck" value="01/04/2013" onfocus="value=" size="10" maxlength="50" />
```

Comment: I made the changes to the html. Thanks. However, the datepicker still will not close in Google Chrome.

Comment: It must be some quirk with Chrome. The datepicker works just fine in IE and Firefox and even in Safari.

Maybe there is some workaround for Chrome?

Comment: Remove the whole `onfocus="value="` attribute. It doesn't make any sense. When I remove it from you code it works fine. Don't forget to remove it in all four datepickers.

Comment: Removing onclick="value" fixed it. Thanks Vlad and everyone for the help!  :)